# If two people of different mass, from rest, pushed off of each other in a frictionless environment, would they both have equal kinetic energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, conservation-laws

I know that momentum would be conserved. I am not looking for this in a homework problem help format because this is not a homework problem. If one person of mass $M$ pushed off of someone with mass $ (2/5)M$ in a frictionless environment, and both started moving, would they have equal or different kinetic energy? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Newton's Third Law, the two people would experience equal forces for equal time. However, the person with lower mass would experience more acceleration, and so would travel a farther distance. Since work is the product of force and distance, the lower-mass person would receive more work, and thus more kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1):

No.
As mentioned above, look at $KE=\frac{p^2}{2m}$.

Because momentum is conserved, both people will have the same value of $p^2$, but since their masses are different, the denominator the kinetic energy term (as written above) will be different for each person.

Answer (score 0):

Their kinetic energy is in general different and is the same if and only if the masses are equal. If their oppositely directed velocities have magnitudes $v_1$ and $v_2$ respectively, then your first sentence shows you understand that $m_1\,v_1=m_2\,v_2$, with $m_j$ being the respective masses.

Now work out the what this condition implies about the ratio $\frac{m_1\,v_1^2}{m_2\,v_2^2}$. In particular, use the above condition to eliminate the velocities from the ratio and you will have all the answers.